# How do I change the sensitivity settings to affect the opacity instead of the brush width?

Tags: grease-pencil

How do I change the sensitivity settings to affect the opacity instead of the brush width for grease pencil, latest update?

It would also be helpful to know which brushes I should use for the sketch and linear.

Answer (score 1):

On top side of the screen disable sensitivity for Radius – and enable sensitivity for Strength.

Screenshot :

[image]